# Which is more preferable? Guard or case?

Tags: erlang

Style 1:

```
a(X) when X>1 -> 
    ...omitted;
a(X) when X ->
    ...omitted.
```

Style 2

```
a(X) ->
    case X>1 of
        true-> ...ommited;
        false-> ...ommited
    end.
```

====Update===

As @rviding said, I update the comparison as following:

Style 1:

```
a(X) when X>1 -> 
    ...omitted;
a(X) ->
    ...omitted.
```

Style 2

```
a(X) ->
    case X>1 of
        true-> ...ommited;
        false-> ...ommited
    end.
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Learn You Some Erlang's section on function syntax](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/syntax-in-functions) states that function clauses and case statements are basically the same, except for one difference: pattern matching in clauses can handle more than one pattern, whereas a case statement can only handle one statement.

Apart from that, I believe it is a matter of taste. I tend to use different function clauses when the cases are really distinct (as in: the complete function will behave differently), and I use case statements when I want the code to diverge and be merged afterwards again, e.g. to calculate the value for a variable based on an expression.

**Edit**
As pointed out by RobertAloi in the comments below, you are not really restricted when using `case .. of`. Also, as rvirding wrote, the compiler does some optimization when wrapping different expressions in a tuple to allow matching against them.

Comment: Thank you. I personally tend to the function clauses as it is more clear. Your advice is well enough to make me do the decision.

Comment: Function clauses are also better to debug as you can trace on them

Comment: @goofansu but in this case avoid the `when X` guard. It will only succeed if `X` has the value `true`.

Comment: @evnu, "whereas a case statement can only handle one statement": what about `case {A,B,...,Z} of ...` ?

Comment: @RobertoAloi You got me there. Your point of critique is correct.

Comment: @evnu If you wrap them in a tuple the compiler will actually optimise away building the tuple until you really need it. But doing in function clauses does still look a little cleaner.

Answer (score 6):

You should also consider that testing the result of a BIF has not the exact same behavior in a guard than inside a function.

I learned this recently, for example `(length(L) > -1)` crashes inside a function but not in a guard when L is an improper list.